# Firebase update multi-factor phone number

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I want to have an option in the app to update MFA phone number.

It seems like using `updatePhoneNumber(credential)` is not correct because phone number must be enrolled as a second factor and not regular first factor auth. Found one [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3247) about it

If I understand correctly, the only way to set a phone number for second factor is to use the following methods:

```
verifyPhoneNumberForMultiFactor(phoneOptions)
```

and then

```
enroll(multiFactorAssertion)
```

But this is a sensitive action. Which means user must be recently logged in. But I don't want to log user out and ask to login again. I want to re-authenticate user instead.

So I can use following flow:

1. Ask user for password (we know email cause user is logged in at this moment)
2. Use `EmailAuthProvider` to re-authenticate user
3. for MFA user it will throw `FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException`
4. Send verification code
5. Ask user for sms code
6. Now user is authenticated and I can ask to set new phone number
7. use `verifyPhoneNumberForMultiFactor` method to send verification code
8. Ask user for sms code
9. Use `enroll` method to update phone number

This flow seems too complicated. Especially if users don't use passwords but email links, so in purpose to re-authenticate I have to ask them to open email and click the link, which makes the flow even crazier.

But even if flow above is valuable, using `enroll` will add a new phone to existing `enrolledFactors` of MFA user, but I need to replace it. And I could not find a method to update specific MFA phone either

What I would like to have is much simpler flow when a user selected what phone number they want to replace, confirm this phone with sms, set another phone, confirm new phone with sms, done.

There's another option - use the Firebase Admin SDK to update `enrolledFactors`, but this action revokes tokens, so I have to ask user to do full login after that. But also I need to invent some method to verify the phone number before asking backend to update it (in purpose to avoid wrong number setup, by a typo for example). But this also breaks another security level firebase has. Every time a new second factor added by `enroll`, firebase sends an email with link to revert this action. With Admin SDK it will not happen.

Is there an easier way to update MFA phone number?

I'm using react-native, but it doesn't matter since methods are similar.